# Show Custom Alert in OnUpdate thread andengine

Tags: android, dialog, andengine, game-engine

```
public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

           mEngine.stop();
           LionActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialoag();
            }
        });
}
```

But it doesn't show any thing on SimpleBaseGameActivity.

Comment: What is the logcat error?? And have you created the Dialog before showing it?

Comment: And can you show us `showCustomDialog();` method?

Comment: void showDialoag() {
dialogCustom = new Dialog(LionActivity.this);  dialogCustom.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialogCustom.setContentView(R.layout.play_again_alert);
  dialogCustom.setCancelable(false);
  dialogCustom.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
  ImageView playagain = (ImageView) dialogCustom
    .findViewById(R.id.playagainnn);

    });

  playagain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // stoptimer();

   }
  });
  dialogCustom.show();

 }

Comment: please put this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment you have used `Dialog` class and directly instantiating it. Please refer the doc from the doc [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) it says :-

> The `Dialog` class is the base class for `dialogs`, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses:
>
> AlertDialog
>   A dialog that can show a title, up to three buttons, a list of selectable items, or a custom layout.

I will suggest you to use `AlertDialog`. Please see the doc aand there is an example how to do that.